# When using Magic Jar, what effects follow the user across bodies?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, possession

There's a [similar question for 3.5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/100105/45363) where the answer is 'unanswered', but I'm hoping there's something in 5e that's different.

To set an example scene:  You're a Draconic Bloodline Sorcerer with *Draconic Resilience*. You're also a Bladesinging Wizard, and you've activated *Bladesong*. You have two *attuned items*. You've cast *Haste* and *Invisibility* on yourself. The Bard has given you *inspiration*. You've been *frightened* by an enemy, but you've *charmed* them back. You proceed to use *Magic Jar* on a random goblin.

What is carried over? What if you did all that as the goblin, then returned to your own body? Do the effects affect the body, or the 'soul'?

Comment: Related questions: "[Does magic jar let you keep background features?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/115737)" and "[How does Magic Jar possession actually interact with your stats?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/59765)" and "[What do “class levels” and “class features” mean in the Magic Jar spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/80069)" and "[Is it possible to maintain concentration while inside of a Magic Jar container?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/154319)" and "[Magic jar's interaction with ability increases and racial feats](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/165811)"

Comment: And "[What happens if you use the Magic Jar spell to possess a creature which has Spellcasting?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/164202)" and "[If a body possessed by a user of Magic Jar is Feebleminded, and the possessor leaves the host body, who was Feebleminded?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/165877)" and "[What happens when a caster's soul returns to his polymorphed body by the effect of Magic Jar?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/167157)" and "[If a character possesses a lich's body via Magic Jar, what benefits of lichdom do they get access to?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/147890)"

Comment: Given the specificity of the questions I've listed above, I personally have voted to close your question as being too broad / needing more focus because it asks about numerous different things each of which could be their own entire question. You can [edit] your question to make it more specific if you would like; but that said, it's also possible other users will conclude that your question *isn't* too broad/general, and that it will remain open.

Answer (score 3):

Magic Jar tends to be one of those spells that's not clear on how all its effects interact with game mechanics. From what it does clarify though we know

> Once you possess a creature’s body, you control it. Your game statistics are replaced by the statistics of the creature, though you retain your alignment and your Intelligence, Wisdom, and Charisma scores. **You retain the benefit of your own class features.** If the target has any class levels, you can’t use any of its class features

Now by RAW since *Draconic Resilience* is a class feature you would still benefit from its effects even though it states

> As magic flows through your body, it causes physical Traits of your Dragon ancestors to emerge. At 1st level, your hit point maximum increases by 1 and increases by 1 again whenever you gain a level in this class.

Some DMs will probably not allow you to gain this effect since it is supposed to be tied to your body

Bladesong is another class feature and again by RAW you will have access to it and its effects when you use magic jar provided that you still follow its restrictions  "**that you aren’t wearing medium or heavy armor or using a shield.**"

The rules are not clear on what counts as attunement with respect to body/soul combo, there is an accepted [answer here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/165875/if-my-simulacrum-possesses-me-via-magic-jar-to-whom-will-my-magic-items-attune) that states that when you use magic jar you dont gain the attuments of the body you posses but makes no mentions of the state of your previous attuments.

With respect to *haste* and *invisibility* based on how the spells are expected to work, I would say neither of the effects would be expected to be carried over. (There are no hard and fast rules that say this, is just what I would do as a DM)

Moving on to the *charmed* and *frightened* conditions I would leave it up to your DM as again there are no rules for this. Personally I would say you would still be frightened by your enemy (and could not use magic jar to get closer to them) and that the enemy would be charmed by the body you were in when you charmed them and not your new body unless you could convince them otherwise